# ng-selected expression returns true but it's not selecting

Tags: angularjs

Here is the select box that I  have added and I need to select an item dynamically.But the problem is that ng-selected expression returns true but it's not selecting the value.

```
<select id="Role" class="form-control" ng-model="rowContent.estimationRoleID"
  style="padding:0 !important">
  <option ng-selected="roles.roleId == rowContent.estimationRoleID"
    ng-repeat="roles in vm.Roles"
    value="{{ roles.roleId }}">
    {{ roles.role }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please create demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo for your issue and it works properly. i think there might be issue in sending data from controller to view.
so you need to check the value(rowContent) comes proper from controller or not.

```js
function testcontroller($scope) {
  $scope.Roles = [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "role": "admin"
  }, {
      "roleId": 2,
      "role": "user"
  }, {
      "roleId": 3,
      "role": "anonymous"
  }];
  $scope.rowContent = {
      "estimationRoleID": 2
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-controller="testcontroller">
   <select id="Role" class="form-control" ng-model="rowContent.estimationRoleID">
      <option ng-selected="roles.roleId == rowContent.estimationRoleID"
         ng-repeat="roles in Roles"
         value="{{ roles.roleId }}">
         {{ roles.role }}
      </option>
   </select>
</body>
```